# Sharing network between jobs in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, playwright

We have a lot of playwright UI tests and it would be great to run them on multiple machines where our backend is run. The backend app is made with Java running postgres as DB.

How I see it:

1. Run workflow
2. workflow setups for example 5 backends running on localhost:3000-3004. This can be 5 jobs or is there any other
   option?
3. Workflow sets up FE repo and playwright within.
4. Playwright pings servers until they are all ready, then starts running tests in parallel.
5. After tests are done. playwright tears down servers and yields reports.

So far what I made.

1. A FE workflow that runs a reusable workflow from BE repo, that spins up backend app. This is done as one job
2. Another job runs playwright tests.

Issue is that the playwright tests can't connect to the localhost on the BE job therefore everything fails.
Did anyone manage to solve this issue? We are coming from Bitbucket where the limitations of it pushed us to find a solution on GitHub.